# C++ - Find and replace in text file (standard system libraries)

Tags: c++, file, text, replace

I am looking for some advice.

**My situation:**

- Application works with **text local file**.
- In file are somewhere tags like this:

  ```
  correct = "TEXT"
  ```

  . Unfortunatelly, there can be unlimited spaces between *correct*, *=* and *"TEXT"*.
- Obtained text is testing in function and may be replaced (the change **must be stored in the file**).

  ```
   correct = "CORRECT_TEXT"
  ```

**My current theoretical approach:**

- With **ofstream** -- read by line to string.
- Find tag and make change in string.
- Save strings as lines to the file.

---

Is there some simplify way (with iterators?) in C++ with using **standard system libraries only** (unix).

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: your title says C++ your tag says C ? These are two different languages, which one do you want?

Comment: @JensGustedt I'm sorry -- mistake. In C++ please.

Comment: What is bad in your current approach? It seems to be quite simple, and anyway `ofstream` is a part of C++ standard library.

Comment: Are you overwriting the same file or generating a new one?

Comment: @Vlad Ok, thanks. I would like to use an effective solution. I don't know for example if it possible find and replace directly in ofstream without using secondury strings.

Comment: @hmjd I need to overwriting the same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that uses:

- [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)
- [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)
- [`ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)
- [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct modified_line
{
    std::string value;
    operator std::string() const { return value; }
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& a_in, modified_line& a_line)
{
    std::string local_line;
    if (std::getline(a_in, local_line))
    {
        // Modify 'local_line' if necessary
        // and then assign to argument.
        //
        a_line.value = local_line;
    }
    return a_in;
}

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream in("file.txt");

    if (in.is_open())
    {
        // Load into a vector, modifying as they are read.
        //
        std::vector<std::string> modified_lines;
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<modified_line>(in),
                  std::istream_iterator<modified_line>(),
                  std::back_inserter(modified_lines));
        in.close();

        // Overwrite.
        std::ofstream out("file.txt");
        if (out.is_open())
        {
            std::copy(modified_lines.begin(),
                      modified_lines.end(),
                      std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, "\n"));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure exactly what the manipulation of the lines should be but you could use:

- [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)
- [`boost::split()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id820181.html)

EDIT:

To avoid storing every line in memory at once the initial `copy()` can changed to write to an alternative file, followed by a file [`rename()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename):

```
std::ifstream in("file.txt");
std::ofstream out("file.txt.tmp");

if (in.is_open() && out.open())
{
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<modified_line>(in),
              std::istream_iterator<modified_line>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, "\n"));

    // close for rename.
    in.close();
    out.close();

    // #include <cstdio>
    if (0 != std::rename("file.txt.tmp", "file.txt"))
    {
        // Handle failure.
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what the purpose of the `modified_line` struct is for. Can't you just use `std::string` directly?

Comment: @Matt, yes you could. The `modified_line` struct can be used to change the line after it has been read from the file but before it is inserted into the `vector`. I didn't write any code that actually changed the line, just a comment, as I am unsure of the transformation required.

Comment: @hmjd Thanks for help :-). It is great that I don't create temporary file, but for big files I need a lot of memory for application. Solution with `vector` looks nice :-).

Comment: @Nanik, just updated answer with alternative that would use a temporary file and only line in memory at any one time.

Comment: @hmjd Perfect solution! I try it by your way. Thank you very much :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can split the task into tiny pieces and figure out how to do each in C++:

- open a file as an input stream
- open temporary file as an output stream
- read a line from a stream
- write a line to a stream
- match a line to given pattern
- replace text in a line
- rename a file

Note: you don't need to store in memory more than one line at a time in this case.

Comment: Thanks :-), it is great that I don't need much memory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot like an 'INI file' syntax. You can search for it and you'll have a big load of examples. However, few of them will actually use C++ stdlib.

Here's some advices. (n.b. I assume that every lines you'll need to replace are using the syntax: `<parameter> = "<value_text>"`)

- Use the `std::string::find` method to locate the '=' character.
- Use the `std::string::substr` method to split the string into different chunks.
- You'll need to create a trim algorithm to remove every blank characters in front or back of a string. (It can be done with std  functions)

With all that you'll then be able to split the string and isolate the parts to compare them do the needed modifications.

have fun !

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to do this within C++? Since you are on Unix, you can call `sed` which would do this easily with a command such as:

```
cat oldfile | sed 's/\(correct *= *\)\"TEXT\"/\1\"CORRECT_TEXT\"/' > newfile
```

You can call unix commands from within C++ if you have to (for example with `system("command")` from `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: Thanks for help :-). I need to do in application, because "TEXT" is corrected by function (dependence on the values ​​of variables). But I can use the idea with call system command, thank you.