# Need some help understanding why wifstream buffer not being saved back to file

Tags: c++, iostream

The following code does exactly what it's supposed to with one exception. The modified buffer content is not being save to the file. I have stepped through the code and I can  see the buffer being changed so I'm not sure what's happening. Any comments would be appreciated.

```
bool replacestring(char *ifile, wstring& searchString, wstring& replacementString)
{
    wstring buffer;
    wifstream finout(ifile, ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);

if(!finout.is_open())
{
    cout << "Can not open file " << endl;
    return(1);
}
while(getline(finout,buffer))
{
    auto pos = buffer.find( searchString ) ;
    while( pos != std::string::npos )
    {
        buffer.replace( pos, searchString.size(), replacementString ) ;
        pos = buffer.find( searchString, pos + replacementString.size() ) ;
    }
    if(finout.bad())
        perror("BAD READ");
}
finout.close();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After you've copied some data from a stream into a buffer, that buffer is separate from the stream, and changes made to the buffer will not be reflected in the stream.

`ifstream` and `wifstream` are input streams, not output streams.

`filebuf` or `wfilebuf` might be what you want instead.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf

Or [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).

It might be easier to just write to a second file using an `ofstream` or `wofstream`. This would also avoid the risk of clobbering the existing file.

Similar question:

- [C++ - Find and replace in text file (standard system libraries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835929/c-find-and-replace-in-text-file-standard-system-libraries)